# How uncommon is it for a Prime Minister not to respond to an urgent question themselves?

Tags: united-kingdom, government, house-of-commons, prime-minister, liz-truss

Quite a lot has been made of Liz Truss not attending the House of Commons to answer an [urgent question](https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/business/urgent-questions/) from the Leader of the Opposition Keir Starmer on her decision to replace the Chancellor of the Exchequer. For example, Starmer accused her of "hiding away, scared of her own shadow", while Penny Mordaunt, who actually answered the question for the PM, told MPs that "the Prime Minister is not under a desk, as the hon. Lady suggests". Media reports are fairly damning as well - [Metro accuses Truss](https://metro.co.uk/2022/10/17/labour-granted-urgent-question-to-pm-after-she-refused-to-come-to-commons-17578511/) of "refusing to answer", while [the Independent says](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/liz-truss-mordaunt-starmer-budget-b2204348.html) that she "dodged MP's questions".

As the Parliament.uk website explains:

> If an urgent or important matter arises which an MP believes requires an immediate answer from a government minister, they may apply to ask an urgent question.
> [...]
> The relevant Government Minister has to come to the Chamber to explain what the Government is doing on the issue raised. The Minister will then usually take questions on the subject from MPs. The Department is also asked to provide a background briefing on the issue for the Speaker and declare any relevant interests.

However, I can't actually remember Boris Johnson ever answering an urgent question addressed to him while he was Prime Minister - as far as I remember they were usually answered by his ministers. Is that right? Is it actually that uncommon for a Prime Minister not to answer urgent questions addressed to them directly? When was the last time this happened?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Tony Blair became Prime Minister in 1997, there have been twenty-eight urgent questions directed to the PM; one to Blair, seven to David Cameron, nine to Theresa May, ten to Boris Johnson, and (so far) just this most recent one to Liz Truss. Gordon Brown wasn't asked any urgent questions.

Of these twenty-eight, only two actually got a response from the Prime Minister themselves; Tony Blair responded to an [urgent question](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2002-11-25/debates/e7a2dd88-93ce-4b1a-bfb7-23968b906827/FireDispute) from Iain Duncan Smith on the 2002 firefighter dispute, and David Cameron responded to an [urgent question](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2012-04-30/debates/1204305000004/MinisterialCode(CultureSecretary)) from Ed Miliband on the conduct of Jeremy Hunt in respect of his dealings with News Corporation. It's perhaps notable that in both cases, the urgent questions came from the leaders of the opposition at that time.

Below is a table of the urgent questions to Prime Ministers since 1997; a Prime Minister has not responded to an urgent question addressed to them in over a decade - even the five questions addressed to Cameron and May by Jeremy Corbyn during his tenure as leader of the opposition were handed off to ministers.

| Date | Questioner | Respondent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [17/10/2022](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2022-10-17/debates/54BB3823-B8E9-405D-B055-F64DC6ACE626/ReplacementOfTheChancellorOfTheExchequer) | Keir Starmer | Penny Mordaunt |
| --------------- | TRUSS | --------------- |
| [26/04/2022](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2022-04-26/debates/2F63783D-9638-4C3D-BED4-537ED4DED86C/PrimeMinister%E2%80%99SVisitToIndia) | Ian Blackford | Vicky Ford |
| [11/01/2022](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2022-01-11/debates/DC167E69-D438-4958-A870-7386FE5DD07C/DowningStreetGardenEvent) | Angela Rayner | Michael Ellis |
| [30/06/2020](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2020-06-30/debates/9846E64F-6A5D-44E5-A98F-4CB6D65D90AF/LammyReview) | David Lammy | Alex Chalk |
| [29/06/2020](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2020-06-29/debates/513FEBBC-DB05-49FF-8903-B5FF88C4BD78/XinjiangUyghurs) | Iain Duncan Smith | Nigel Adams |
| [15/06/2020](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2020-06-15/debates/AE7AB431-1668-4AAA-AA32-8A0B83124D30/SocialDistancing2MetreRule) | Greg Clark | Edward Argar |
| [02/03/2020](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2020-03-02/debates/ACE798E4-1624-4BF6-95EC-DFD60C266F05/MinisterialCode) | Jeremy Corbyn | Michael Gove |
| [05/11/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-11-05/debates/AABC4DE9-4D70-4937-9AF5-D58CE7B0601D/IntelligenceAndSecurityCommitteeReportOnRussia) | Dominic Grieve | Christopher Pincher |
| [21/10/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-10-21/debates/62684B73-EADD-4C56-B981-6D153F818E7F/EuropeanUnion(WithdrawalAgreement)BillAndExtensionLetter) | Jeremy Corbyn | Stephen Barclay |
| [26/09/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-09-26/debates/4BFC992D-7B89-467B-9042-0B8345943D39/ComplianceWithTheEuropeanUnion(Withdrawal)(No2)Act2019) | Ian Murray | James Duddridge |
| [26/09/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-09-26/debates/B7A6C9A8-DCA4-4599-8698-340BF500CE5D/PrimeMinisterSRoleInCreatingASafeEnvironment) | Jess Phillips | Kevin Foster |
| --------------- | JOHNSON | --------------- |
| [15/07/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-07-15/debates/A28DF0EC-D0D6-4792-A767-B2295B328543/DetaineeMistreatmentJudge-LedInquiry) | Kenneth Clarke | David Lidington |
| [02/05/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-05-02/debates/F010321A-9805-4159-9D27-57AD560ED880/NationalSecurityCouncilLeak) | Tom Watson | David Lidington |
| [22/03/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-03-22/debates/92131522-6FFF-49AF-BA5C-F68A7A557FE1/EmergencySummitOnKnifeCrime) | Louise Haugh | Victoria Atkins |
| [20/03/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-03-20/debates/AD043295-65EC-4E63-9917-E206FAD31A17/No-DealEUExitPreparations) | John Baron | Chris Heaton-Harris |
| [11/03/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-03-11/debates/239E2D46-3815-4CD5-B97A-E95639760188/EUWithdrawalAgreementLegalChanges) | Jeremy Corbyn | Robin Walker |
| [20/02/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-02-20/debates/47C7C0C7-87DD-4A98-94E3-D7FBAEAF290A/LeavingTheEUEconomicImpactOfProposedDeal) | Ian Blackford | Mel Stride |
| [07/01/2019](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-01-07/debates/06CD74FD-CAC2-401F-AF97-015146AF7756/EUWithdrawalAgreementLegalChanges) | Jeremy Corbyn | Stephen Barclay |
| [30/04/2018](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2018-04-30/debates/E7547DA9-5D22-4EC0-BAB4-8FC71BD2E1F9/Windrush) | Diane Abbott | Sajid Javid |
| [20/03/2017](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2017-03-20/debates/2E21C4BD-BC87-4E2B-9E3D-2844214108F6/AdvisoryCommitteeOnBusinessAppointmentsMinisterialCode) | Andrew Gwynne | Ben Gummer |
| --------------- | MAY | --------------- |
| [28/04/2016](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2016-04-28/debates/16042846000003/TradeUnionBill(Discussions)) | Bernard Jenkin | Nick Boles |
| [09/03/2016](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2016-03-09/debates/16030943000005/EU-TurkeyAgreement) | John Redwood | David Lidington |
| [29/02/2016](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2016-02-29/debates/16022911000004/EUReferendumCivilServiceGuidance) | Bernard Jenkin | Matthew Hancock |
| [02/02/2016](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2016-02-02/debates/16020258000001/UK%E2%80%99SRelationshipWithTheEU) | Jeremy Corbyn | David Lidington |
| [21/07/2015](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2015-07-21/debates/15072125000006/DWPData) | Debbie Abrahams | Priti Patel |
| [07/01/2014](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2014-01-07/debates/14010734000001/EuropeanCouncil) | Gisela Stuart | David Lidington |
| [30/04/2012](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2012-04-30/debates/1204305000004/MinisterialCode(CultureSecretary)) | Edward Miliband | David Cameron |
| --------------- | CAMERON | --------------- |
| --------------- | BROWN | --------------- |
| [25/11/2002](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2002-11-25/debates/e7a2dd88-93ce-4b1a-bfb7-23968b906827/FireDispute) | Iain Duncan Smith | Tony Blair |
| --------------- | BLAIR | --------------- |

Comment: Is it worth including something about why Urgent Questions have increased? TB and DC responded personally because these were almost unique events. They've since become a regular part of the non-government benches toolkit.

Comment: @Jontia I don't know the answer to that, unfortunately - if I had to guess, I'd say John Bercow's speakership led to a lot more UQs being granted, but as there's no data on rejected UQs I can't be sure. That's probably something that could be FOI'd though.